# $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors using ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I have been using this script for a while and it seems to worked ok, until now.

When I use this file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/onqp2bv1ch0346m/pbt.csv?dl=0

To  run the following script:

```
   pbt=read.csv("pbt.csv")
   colnames(pbt)
   tp95=ddply(pbt,.(ind),summarize,
       tp95=subset(pbt,
                   pbt=quantile(pbt$pbt, c(.025),na.rm=T))
                   &pbt=quantile(pbt$pbt, c(.975),na.rm=T))
```

I get the following error:
Error in pbt$pbt : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

What is the reason of this error? how can i overcome it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `class(pbt)` show you?

Comment: it gives me "data.frame"

Answer (score 0):

You are masking the `pbt` variable inside your call to `subset`.  Just rename your data frame to something else:

```
df <- read.csv("pbt.csv")
colnames(df)
tp95 <- ddply(df,
              .(ind),summarize,
              tp95=subset(df, pbt=quantile(df$pbt, c(.025),na.rm=T))
              &pbt=quantile(df$pbt, c(.975),na.rm=T))
```